# Tornado server stopped error: exception triggered

Tags: python, server, tornado

I am getting the following error after I run the following command:

```
$ sudo python server.py
Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped.
```

I've researched this particular error but haven't come across any similar errors with a solution or explanation.

Any idea as to what might be causing this?

The relevant portion of server.py is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
           http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
           http_server.listen(PORT)
           main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

           print "Tornado Server started"
           main_loop.start()

    except:
           print "Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped."
           GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: We need to see `server.py`, and you should `try-except` something to get a more useful message

Comment: I added the relevant code from `server.py` to my question!

Comment: You printed your own custom message... Why are you asking us what it means? Or why you thought it was searchable